# Geting Speed From GPS on Android Calculating Distance And Time

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I have been trying to get speed by the help of GPS. I would like to get Gps datas(latitude-longitude-speed) when my telephone fell down.

When telephone fell down, gps datas are obtained and sent to my server. For this aim, I used threads. Each thread get gps datas and send to server them.

My problem is speed value. I got speed calculating distance between two location and time 
(speed = distance / time)

Thread makes :

```
@Override
public void run() {

    Looper.prepare();

    float distance = 0.0f;
    float[] results = new float[1];
    Long longValue = new Long(11);
    double firstLatitude;
    double firstLongitude;
    long firstTime;
    float speedOfDevice = 0.0f;

    //for sendin gps datas to web server
    ReportLocation reportObj = new ReportLocation(this);

    locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);

    //latitude, longitude and timeOffix is set in location listener
    firstLatitude = latitude;
    firstLongitude = longitude;
    firstTime = timeOfFix;

    // Waiting 1.5 second 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sleep exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);


    if( timeOfFix != firstTime ) {
        Location.distanceBetween(firstLatitude, firstLongitude, latitude, longitude, results);
        distance = results[0];
        longValue = new Long(timeOfFix - firstTime );
        speedOfDevice = 3600 * distance / ( longValue.floatValue() ); 
    }

    try {

        reportObj.send( Double.toString(firstLatitude),  Double.toString(firstLongitude), Float.toString( speedOfDevice ) );

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "Client protokol exception ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "IO exception "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    Looper.loop();
}
```

}

---

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {

            locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); 

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            timeOfFix = location.getTime();

        }  
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I tried my program in the car that in motion. But I couldn't get correct speed datas.. For example 7.31365 , 8.29663 etc.. They should be 50- 60 or 70 km/h..

What are your thoughts ?

Comment: Are the locations returned correct?

Comment: Yes, locations returned correct. But firstLatitude and latitude or fistLongitude and longitude values may same sometimes. I don't understand it..

Comment: I am wondering if your implementation is correct. The listener should get back to the calling service/thread/activity with a call back (check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a). In addition, I think it will stop working when the phone goes to sleep mode

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if your implementation is correct. I think the problem is that the location updates are not connected to the fix of a new location. So if your gps did not make a new fix, then the current location will be sent again.

A logic could be that every X seconds, you turn on your  requestLocationUpdates() process the location if/when it is received and turn off updates (removeUpdates())
Check this post for an excellent example (that solved many problems for me): [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

The example above is clear to understand.
The tricky part is to use it in a service as a service does not work when the phone goes on sleep mode. Here you can use a [commonsware component](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) to overcome this.

I have used and mixed those two components to set up a location service and it is stable.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks.. I will analyze example you suggested.