# How to calculate the average distance ,speed and time on nutiteq while tracking

Tags: android, maps, nutiteq

I am experimenting using nutiteq , as i found it a better alternative working on 3d maps.I want to learn every bit of it.So I am making a simple project where I can calculate the speed distance and time from its current location simultaneously on its tracking.
I applied some logics but failed.Can any of you help me.

```
public final static double AVERAGE_RADIUS_OF_EARTH = 6371;
public int calculateDistance(double userLat, double userLng, double venueLat, double venueLng) {

        double latDistance = Math.toRadians(userLat - venueLat);
        double lngDistance = Math.toRadians(userLng - venueLng);

        double a = (Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)) +
                        (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(userLat))) *
                        (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(venueLat))) *
                        (Math.sin(lngDistance / 2)) *
                        (Math.sin(lngDistance / 2));

        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

        return (int) (Math.round(AVERAGE_RADIUS_OF_EARTH * c));

    }
```

This is what I have used so far and is calling this function onLocationChange.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: this is the best way to calculate distance

Comment: But its not working.I donot know, where do i go wrong in my code.I am adding this line of code also but no use:  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, crit.getAccuracy() , 0 , locationListener);
        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: for reference you can follow links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410698/calculating-speed-for-a-navigation-app-without-getspeed-method  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808004/geting-speed-from-gps-on-android-calculating-distance-and-time and you have to use locationManager.requestLocationUpdates() or just run service that fetch location's lat long and calculate distance or you can use android.location.Location.distanceBetween() method also

Comment: use AVERAGE_RADIUS_OF_EARTH = 6371; to AVERAGE_RADIUS_OF_EARTH = 6371000;

Comment: hey have you find any solution ??and if yes then can you provide me solution

Comment: Yes i have added the code and is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my code and is working well:

```
case R.id.btn_StartTrack:

                location_manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                provider = location_manager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                //location.getAccuracy();

                if (location_manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                {

                    if (!isclickedBtnStartTrackFirstTym)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < geoLayerList.size(); i++)
                        {
                            mapView.getLayers().removeLayer(geoLayerList.get(i));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < markerlist.size(); i++)
                        {
                            mapView.getLayers().removeLayer(markerlist.get(i));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < markerlist1.size(); i++)
                        {
                            mapView.getLayers().removeLayer(markerlist1.get(i));
                        }
                        geoLayerList = new ArrayList<GeometryLayer>();
                        geoLayerList.clear();
                        markerlist = new ArrayList<MarkerLayer>();
                        markerlist.clear();
                        markerlist1 = new ArrayList<MarkerLayer>();
                        markerlist1.clear();
                        journeyDuration = 0;
                        totalSpeed = 0.0;
                        averageSpeed = 0.0;
                        distanceInMiles = 0.0;
                        distanceInMilesRound=0.0;
                        mtvCalcTime.setText("00:00");
                        mtvCalcDistance.setText("0:00");
                        mtvCalcSpeed.setText("0.0");
                        isclickedBtnStartTrackFirstTym = true;
                        btn_startTrack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_tracking);
                        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                        journey_id = String.valueOf(date.getTime());


                        location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, activity);

                        startJourneyTimer();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        location_manager.removeUpdates(activity);

                        if (!arr_lat_long.isEmpty())
                        {
                             last_pos = arr_lat_long.get(arr_lat_long.size() - 1);
                            Bitmap pointMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pointer);
                            MarkerStyle markerStyle = MarkerStyle.builder().setBitmap(pointMarker).setSize(0.5f).setAllowOverlap(false).setColor(Color.WHITE).build();
                            Label markerLabel = new DefaultLabel("");
                            markerLayer1 = new MarkerLayer(mapView.getComponents().layers.getBaseProjection());
                            Marker marker = new Marker(last_pos, markerLabel, markerStyle, null);
                            markerLayer1.add(marker);

                            markerlist.add(markerLayer1);
                            mapView.getLayers().addLayer(markerLayer1); 

                        }

                        btn_startTrack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_tracking);
                        mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mlinbtns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layoutVisibility = "2";
                        isclickedBtnStartTrackFirstTym = false;
                        if (timer != null)
                        {
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Utilities.buildAlertMessageNoGps(getActivity());
                }
                break;
    }



    /**
    *
    *  onLoctionChanged
    */

    @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            double accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
            if(accuracy<=30)
            {

            Tripname = "tripname";
            Double newLat = location.getLatitude();
            Double newLong = location.getLongitude();

            lat_current = location.getLatitude();
            lng_current = location.getLongitude();

            if (endLatitude == -180)
            {
                endLatitude = newLat;
                endLongitude = newLong;
            }
            else
            {
                startLatitude = endLatitude;
                startLongitude = endLongitude;

                endLatitude = newLat;
                endLongitude = newLong;
            }

            double speed = (double) location.getSpeed();


            speedInmph = JourneyUtils.getSpeedInMiles(speed); // method for speed t mph and kmph

            totalSpeed = averageSpeed + speedInmph;
            averageSpeed = totalSpeed / 2;
            averageSpeed = Utilities.roundTwoDecimals(averageSpeed); 
            mtvCalcSpeed.setText(averageSpeed + "");    
            if (startLatitude != -180)
            {
                double distance = JourneyUtils.getDistanceInMiles(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude);
                distanceInMiles = distance + distanceInMiles;
                distanceInMilesRound = Utilities.roundTwoDecimals(distanceInMiles);
                mtvCalcDistance.setText(distanceInMilesRound + "");
            }

            long newTimeInMillis = location.getTime();

            String utcDateTime = Utilities.getUTCDateTimeFromMillis(newTimeInMillis);
            //mtvCalcTime.setText(utcDateTime);


            db_journeySave.insertjourney(journey_id, utcDateTime, newLat + "", newLong + "", distanceInMiles + "", speedInmph + "", accuracy + "", Tripname, 0, 0, localTime1 + ":00");

            mapView.getCameraPos();

            MapPos lineLocation = mapView.getLayers().getBaseProjection().fromWgs84(endLongitude, endLatitude);

            arr_lat_long.add(lineLocation);
            ArrayList<MarkerLayer> arr_markerlist = new ArrayList<MarkerLayer>();
            if (arr_lat_long.size() > 1)
            {
                MapPos start_lat = arr_lat_long.get(0);
                Bitmap pointMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_pointer);
                MarkerStyle markerStyle = MarkerStyle.builder().setBitmap(pointMarker).setSize(0.5f).setAllowOverlap(false).setColor(Color.WHITE).build();
                Label markerLabel = new DefaultLabel("");
                MarkerLayer markerLayer = new MarkerLayer(mapView.getComponents().layers.getBaseProjection());
                Marker marker = new Marker(start_lat, markerLabel, markerStyle, null);
                markerLayer.add(marker);
                markerlist.add(markerLayer);
                mapView.getLayers().addLayer(markerLayer);



                MapPos last_pos1 = arr_lat_long.get(arr_lat_long.size() - 1);

                Bitmap movingMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue);
                MarkerStyle markerStyle1 = MarkerStyle.builder().setBitmap(movingMarker).setSize(0.5f).setAllowOverlap(false).setColor(Color.WHITE).build();
                Label markerLabel1 = new DefaultLabel("");
                MarkerLayer markerLayer1 = new MarkerLayer(mapView.getComponents().layers.getBaseProjection());
                Marker marker1 = new Marker(last_pos1, markerLabel1, markerStyle1, null);

                markerLayer1.add(marker1);  
                mapView.getLayers().addLayer(markerLayer1);
                arr_markerlist.add(markerLayer1);
                if(arr_markerlist.size()>0)
                {
                    markerLayer1.remove(marker1);
                    mapView.getLayers().removeLayer(markerLayer1);
                }

                geoLayer = new GeometryLayer(mapView.getComponents().layers.getBaseProjection());
                mapView.getLayers().addLayer(geoLayer);
                geoLayerList.add(geoLayer);
                StyleSet<LineStyle> lineStyleSet = new StyleSet<LineStyle>(LineStyle.builder().setWidth(0.15f).setColor(Color.CYAN).build());
                ArrayList<MapPos> arr1_lat_long = new ArrayList<MapPos>();
                arr1_lat_long.add(arr_lat_long.get(arr_lat_long.size() - 2));
                arr1_lat_long.add(arr_lat_long.get(arr_lat_long.size() - 1));
                line = new Line(arr1_lat_long, null, lineStyleSet, null);
                geoLayer.add(line);

            }
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
```